# how to change size of the element using css?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to do transform a image using css keyframe

I have something like

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinkscale {
    0% {    
        transform: scale(1,1)
    }
    50% {        
        transform: scale(0.1,0.1)
    }
    100% {        
        transform: scale(3,3)
    }
}

.addScale {
    -webkit-animation: blinkscale 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation: blinkscale 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation: blinkscale 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

html

```
   <img src='test.jpg' class='addScale' />
```

It works if I change my keyframe to

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinkscale {
   0% {background: yellow;}
  50% {background: green;} 
  100% {background: blue;}
}
```

but not the scale one. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what browser are you using for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you. Just have to make sure the vendor prefixes persist.

#### CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinkscale {
    0% {    
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1)
    }
    50% {        
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1,0.1)
    }
    100% {        
        -webkit-transform: scale(3,3)
    }
}
```

Also to note, you have `-moz-` and `-o-` animation set to `.addScale` so be sure to set keyframes to accommodate all those vendor prefixes and don't forget the standard `animation` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This link here should be of use [Keyframe Animations](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Maybe you haven't included the proper browser help, in the webkit keyframes blinkscale, I only see the help for mozilla,.